# Show authors blog posts in reverse chronological order

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sorting, blog

Currently, *all* of the blog posts for a given author on the newly re-designed SE blog platform are displayed in a chronological order (beginning with the oldest).

For example, right now it takes 7 clicks (and could possibly *more* if the new posts are added) to reach to the newest blog post made by author [Joel Spolsky](http://blog.stackexchange.com/authors/spolsky/). That's lot of work (and kinda annoying too) to just find out the authors latest blog post(s). I think it would be better if we could change the sort order of posts in reverse chronological order (from newest to oldest). In the meantime, I am using hacky way (modifying the **page#** (obtained from bottom right "PAGE 1 OF 7") in the URL) to get the latest post. But it shouldn't be this hard.

I would like to make a feature request to display authors blog posts in reverse chronological order (from newest to oldest). If this is not feasible (due to some technical reasons), then at least give an option to sort them in reverse chronological order.

Please share your thoughts, ideas or any suggestions.

Comment: This might also help: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261256/230506

Comment: @James yes, adding a Calendar will definitely help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this was fixed  as of this commit: [6493d48](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/commit/6493d48bf93f8f73ddcb6c26e7c73309069944a9).

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Glad to see [status-completed] tag.